# Adding a .NET Core back-end to an Aurelia project

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, aurelia

I have my front end in Aurelia and I'm trying to add a .NET Core back-end. My back-end is supposed to send some data to the front-end and also receive data that's submitted from the front-end. I tried the following:

```
mkdir app
cd app
dotnet new webapi
au new --here
```

This works fine but the back-end is listening on port 5000 and my front-end is listening on port 8080. Is this the right way to add a .NET Core back-end and is it good practice to have both your front and back-end running on different ports?

Comment: The idea of .Net Core is to host independent of Front end web server and database server in any platform or container like Docker. While in development environment different port acts as different hosting / server. So, you don't need two computers to test end to end solutions.

Comment: thank you for your feedback, does that mean I need to different computers on production? how does it work exactly? I have never pushed something into production

Comment: You may host it in same server having IIS by creating different web applications on IIS. So, one web application will be having front end scripts and html/css while other web application will point to the wwwroot directory.

Comment: okay thank you! you don't see any red flags with what I have so far?

Comment: Till the time your front end is properly hitting the .net core api and getting httpresponse message back. Everything is good! !!

Comment: sounds good, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this the right way to add a .NET Core back-end

If you would like to add a new `ASP.NET Core` project for `Aurelia`, there's no need to invent your own workflow. **You don't have to create your `ASP.NET Core` project**.

Simply use `au new`( without `dotnet new webapi` ) :

```
    PS aurelia-app-hello> au new helloworld --here
    No Aurelia project found.
                          _ _          ____ _     ___
      __ _ _   _ _ __ ___| (_) __ _   / ___| |   |_ _|
     / _` | | | | '__/ _ \ | |/ _` | | |   | |    | |
    | (_| | |_| | | |  __/ | | (_| | | |___| |___ | |
     \__,_|\__,_|_|  \___|_|_|\__,_|  \____|_____|___|


    Which module loader / bundler would you like to use?

    1. Webpack (Default)
       A powerful and popular bundler for JavaScript
    2. CLI's built-in bundler with RequireJS
       RequireJS is a mature and stable module loader for JavaScript.
    3. CLI's built-in bundler with SystemJS
       SystemJS is Dynamic ES module loader, the most versatile module loader for JavaScript

    [Webpack]>

    What platform are you targeting?

    1. Web (Default)
       The default web platform setup.
    2. ASP.NET Core
       A powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites with .NET.

    [Web]> 2
```

**Choose the 2nd option**, and the `au-cli` will create a `ASP.NET Core` project for you. It will also setup all the configurations automatically.

> is it good practice to have both your front and back-end running on different ports?

Don't worry. You're in the right direction. If you look into the [source code of SPA](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/JavaScriptServices/src/) by ASP.NET Core team, you'll find out that they are also doing the same thing as you. When there's an incoming related message, the ASP.NET Core server will simply proxy it to dev server.

For example, [the default project template for creating ASP.NET Core application with Angular](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Templating/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates/content/Angular-CSharp) uses the `angular-cli` to start front end dev server on a port, which is different from the one listened by ASP.NET Core.

As a side note, the "front end" project only runs when in development. There's no need to care about the performance.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer

Comment: after selecting webpack step, i get no option to select the platfrom.